# passing a variable value in with_items that is used in uri call

Tags: ansible

I am not sure if this is possible but here is what I am trying to do. I appreciate if any inputs.

I have a jinja2 template that have one variable value

say `template.json.j2`

```
{
  "index_patterns": "{{ pattern }}"
 }
```

and in my playbook, I have this API call

```
uri:
  url: "https://{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8100/_index_template/{{ item.name }}
  method: PUT
  body: "{{ lookup('template', item.path) }}
with_items:
  - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test1' }
  - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test2' }
  - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test3' }
```

for `test1`, I want to have a different `index_patterns` value and so is for `test2` ..how can I pass my `{{ pattern }}` value dynamically in my `template.json.j2` based on the `name` in `with_items`?

may be something like this `{ path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test1', pattern: 'abcd' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. As you mentioned you can pass `{ path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test1', pattern: 'abcd' }` in `with_items`. Then add the `pattern` variable as `vars` to the task which would reference `item.pattern`.

Like below:

```yaml
  - uri:
      url: "https://{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8100/_index_template/{{ item.name }}"
      method: PUT
      body: "{{ lookup('template', item.path) }}"
    with_items:
      - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test1', pattern: 'foo' }
      - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test2', pattern: 'bar' }
      - { path: 'template.json.j2', name: 'test3', pattern: 'baz' }
    vars:
      pattern: "{{ item.pattern }}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out and accept the answer.